# Add default parrot comments automatically

Tags: resharper

Never mind for a second the fact this may be stuipid, but I want to add default parrot comments such as:

```
/// <summary>
/// Constructor
/// </summary>
public AAbout()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}        

/// <summary>
/// Foo
/// </summary>
Don't want parameters defaulted
public Foo( int param)
{
}
```

except maybe this is impossible for Ctor but that's fine. I also want this for properties but not fields. This is a coding standard at my company this isn't my standard, lets not get into that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can define custom templates for this. Go to Resharper -> Templates Explorer. Add new template like shown below:
[image]
Then you can use it in code edit just typed 'constr'. You can define additional templates for property generation (or edit existed). And if you are using R# 6+, you can share your templates as part of R# settings with your team. Read more about R# templates [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/codeTemplate.html).

Comment: Thats great, is there a place online to grab some templates which are common.

Comment: Common templates is shipped by default with resharper. Additional templates you can find after quick googling, for example: http://www.developerdame.com/?p=269 and http://www.drewnoakes.com/code/resharper/